# Bongard n°4: Neutral vs Town

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, bongard

[image]

This is my last puzzle before the holidays, have a nice summer everyone.
Here's a [link](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html) to the rules of these kind of problems:

> There are six boxes on the left, and another six on the right. **The
>   ones on the left conform to a pattern, or rule, that describes them**,
>   and the task of the problem-solver is to **find this pattern, or rule.**
>   As an aid, the six **boxes on the right do not conform to the same
>   pattern**. Sometimes they conform to a different pattern (as is the case
>   in the above example), while in some cases the rule that describes
>   them is simply the negation of the rule on the left. (Thus, the six
>   boxes on the left are the ones that, somehow, have the official status
>   of defining the pattern.)

Comment: If that can help: (rot13) uggc://jjj.oynaxzrqvntnzrf.pbz/ebyrf/

Comment: Since you removed both tags for trivia and knowledge, I will now assume that no knowledge about this game is required to be able to solve it. Please place them back if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: @PL457 the puzzle does not require any external sources nor specific knowledge, I provided the link to the rules in the puzzle

Comment: This is so difficult. What almost work is rot13[abg orvat noyr gb qenj na havagreehcgrq fgenvtug yvar orgjrra gur yrsgzbfg naq evtugzbfg rkgerzr cbvagf], but alas that *just* fails for the bottom-right one.

Comment: @jafe not usre what you mean with that...

Comment: @SilverCookies Take the leftmost rightmost points and draw a straight line between them. Here I've marked the line green if it stays inside the shape the entire way, and red otherwise: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7rbL.png But again, it doesn't quite work :/

Comment: @jafe Oh I see now. Nice thinking but that's not it.

Comment: Who's that Pokemon?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is the intended solution, but it does correctly partition the sets:

> For each box, count the number of pixels in the silhouette (don't consider the box border) that are not white (255,255,255,255 in the png file). Then count the fraction of these pixels that are "edges", in that they are adjacent to a white pixel. If the fraction is greater than 2.6%, the figure is on the left. If less than 2.6%, it is on the right.

Intuitively,

> The images on the left seem to have more edges and less fill, if you just eyeball them without looking too closely.

Comment: That may not be the intended format of the solution, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if it were closely related to the real solution in some way.

Comment: Wrong. But good attempt. As Ben said, not too far from the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint given by @Saeidryl in comment, maybe the answer is

> fictitious versus real

On the left:

> apocalypse-arsonist plaguebearer necromancer nosferatu Jester werewolf

On the right

> doctor townie-female spy jailor bodyguard crusader

Comment: First guess was wrong so no longer an answer but not deleting it to help better inspire ones

Comment: "arbitrary" differences like the one suggested by you are forbidden in Bongard, I will add the rules to the question. You can consider it the theme of the question I guess, but it has nothing to do with the answer